# how to add haptic or sound to my custom keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, custom-keyboard, haptic-feedback

I want to add haptic and sound to my custom keyboard.

Here is my code.

```
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
generator.prepare()
generator.impactOccurred()
```

What's wrong?